# Opposite of smtpd_tls_ask_ccert for SMTP?

Tags: postfix

What is the way to offer my cert when sending outgoing mail?

All outgoing mail says "No Client Certificate offered".

EDIT:
Self signing a new certificate didn't help either.

This what I have in the TLS section of the main.cf file:

```
# TLS parameters
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtp_tls_mandatory_protocols = TLSv1
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
smtp_tls_ciphers = export
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/postfix/public.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/postfix/private.pem
smtpd_tls_CApath = /etc/postfix/
smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/postfix/comodoca.pem
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtp_tls_cert_file=/etc/postfix/client.pem
smtp_tls_key_file = /etc/postfix/clientprivate.pem
smtp_tls_CApath = /etc/postfix/
smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/postfix/clientca.pem
smtp_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_tls_exclude_ciphers = RC4,MD5, aNULL
smtp_tls_exclude_ciphers = RC4, MD5, aNULL
smtpd_tls_ask_ccert = yes
```

Answer (score 0):

See Postfix TLS readme, [Client-side certificate and private key configuration](http://www.postfix.org/TLS_README.html#client_cert_key):

> RSA key and certificate examples:
>
> ```
> /etc/postfix/main.cf:
>     smtp_tls_cert_file = /etc/postfix/client.pem
>     smtp_tls_key_file = $smtp_tls_cert_file
> ```
>
> Their DSA counterparts:
>
> ```
> /etc/postfix/main.cf:
>     smtp_tls_dcert_file = /etc/postfix/client-dsa.pem
>     smtp_tls_dkey_file = $smtp_tls_dcert_file
> ```
>
> Their ECDSA counterparts (Postfix ≥ 2.6 + OpenSSL ≥ 1.0.0):
>
> ```
> /etc/postfix/main.cf:
>     smtp_tls_eccert_file = /etc/postfix/client-ecdsa.pem
>     smtp_tls_eckey_file = $smtp_tls_eccert_file
> ```

While the TLS readme gives a good overview on the topic, you may also need to consult details on individual [Postfix Configuration Parameters](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html).

Comment: I already have those in place. Still doesn't offer the cert. CheckTLS Still says: ====tls negotiation successful (cypher: DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384, client cert: Subject Name: undefined;Issuer  Name: undefined;)"

Answer (score 0):

To advertise STARTTLS, Postfix has two configuration options:

```
smtpd_use_tls=yes
```

With this, Postfix will announce STARTTLS availability for incoming SMTP-Connections (for the SMTP-Daemon)

```
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer=yes
```

And this enables the announcement for outgoing SMTP connections.

Comment: I have those two in place already. I guess this means that it's not using my cert. It is a Comodo PositiveSSL Wildcard certificate. Works perfect for incoming; I verified this with CheckTLS. This same exact certificate works fine with my Exchange Edge server on CheckTLS. Should I bundle the public key with the private key like the Postfix documentation says I can?

Comment: I answered my own question, combining the private and public key didn't fix it. How am I supposed to get a client cert? I thought client certs usually are for an email address.

Comment: @user2539458 *"I thought client certs usually are for an email address."* No, "client" in this case refers to the SMTP client, not to the identity. A single Postfix server is typically serving many users with different e-mail addresses, possibly on multiple domains, so a certificate for a specific e-mail address wouldn't be useful for the server's SMTP transaction.

Comment: I understand that. It is just very frustrating. I have everything in place. Read a LOT before I even bothered to post here. Don't like to waste people's time :) I am slowly giving up on it, considering that I really don't need it to use TLS. The certificate is good, not revoked, and it's NOT self signed.